# How to add menu items to menu at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, navigation

Can I add items to menu dynamically, I have a empty menu in my master page and in server side

```
Page load()
{
  NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
  {
    Text = "About Us",
    NavigateUrl = "~/AboutUs.aspx"        
  });
  if ((Session["uPermission"].ToString() == null))
  {        
    NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
    {
      Text = "   Support",
      NavigateUrl = "~/Support.aspx"        
    });

  }
  else if ((Session["uPermission"].ToString() == "SuperAdmin") || (Session["uPermission"].ToString() == "OrgAdmin"))
  {

  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in master page server side. I tried debugging it and the error is Null reference exception"Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Session["uPermission"].ToString() == null
```

Should just be `Session["uPermission"] == null` you can't `ToString()` a `null`

Answer (score 3):

`if(Session["uPermission"] == null)`

rather than `Session["uPermission"].ToString() == null`